# Get the size of the output zip file using NodeJs

Tags: node.js, express, download, node-archiver

I'm using `NodeJs` (expressJs) and `archiver` module to stream zip file to the client, so the final ZIP file do not existe in server storage (`streaming zip serving`), but the probleme is that i can't get the size of the output file because the zip process happen in real time.

Code :

```
var archiver = require('archiver');
var files = ["file1","file2"];
var zipper = archiver('zip');

zipper.on('error', function(err) {
res.status(500).send({
    error: err.message
});
});

res.attachment('output.zip');
res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/zip');
zipper.pipe(res);
files.forEach(f => {
zipper.file(f, {
    name: f
});
});

zipper.finalize();
```

Comment: Any help please !

Comment: Hey man, did you ever find a work around for this ? Im facing exactly the same problem

Answer (score 1):

You have listen for the `"data"` event on the readable stream.
Here zipper is a readable stream,so you can calculate the whole size by adding the size of each chunk.

```
var sizeOfZipFile = 0;
zipper.on('data', (chunk) => {
 sizeOfZipFile += chunk.length 
});
console.log(sizeOfZipFile) //logs the size of the zip file
```

Comment: but the size info will be available before stating download file ?

Comment: we can't find the full size of streams ahead without a workaround.There is an npm module that usually works.Check the link https://www.npmjs.com/package/stream-length

Comment: I can help if you share some runnable code with comments

Comment: Any further development on this?  I was also looking for a way of predicting file size without actually performing the write eg. compress in memory and if size exceeds certain size the don't write.